# Specify the percentColWidth for datagrid column in action script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

Tried

```
col.setStyle('percentWidth',20) //doesn't work

col.setStyle('percentWidth',0.2)//doesn't work
```

&&

```
col.percentWidth //doesnt compile
```

where col is one of the columns in a datagrid

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following extended datagrid:

```
package {
import mx.controls.DataGrid;
import mx.events.DataGridEvent;

public class ExDataGrid extends DataGrid {

    //--------------------------------------
    //   Constructor 
    //--------------------------------------

    public function ExDataGrid() {
        super();
        addEventListener(DataGridEvent.COLUMN_STRETCH, onColumnStretch);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //   Properties 
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //--------------------------------------
    //   Private 
    //--------------------------------------

    /**
     * @private
     * Keeps track of whether the columns have been manually adjusted or not. If they
     * have, then do not apply the columnWidths that have been specified.
     */
    private var _columnsAdjusted : Boolean = false;

    /**
     * @private
     * Storage for the columnWidths property.
     */
    private var _columnWidths : Array = new Array();

    /**
     * @private
     */
    private var _columnWidthsChanged : Boolean = false;

    /**
     * @private
     * Stores the explicit width portions of the column widths.
     */
    private var _explicitColWidths : Object;

    /**
     * @private
     * Stores the percentage width portions of the column widths.
     */
    private var _percentColWidths : Object;

    //--------------------------------------
    //   Getters / Setters 
    //--------------------------------------

    public function get columnWidths() : Array {
        return _columnWidths;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the widths of each of the columns. The widths can either be percentages or
     * explicit widths. For each column in the DataGrid, there should be a column width
     * value. The column widths should be expressed as strings.
     *
     * If there are 4 columns and we want the 1st column to be 40% width, the 2nd column
     * to be 60% width, the 3rd column to be a fixed width of 200, and the 4th column to
     * be a fixed width of 300. Then we would set the columnWidths property to be:
     * ['40%', '60%', 200, 300]
     */
    public function set columnWidths(values : Array) : void {
        if (_columnWidths != values) {
            _columnWidths = values;
            _columnWidthsChanged = true;

            invalidateProperties();
            invalidateDisplayList();
        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //   Functions  
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //--------------------------------------
    //   Protected 
    //--------------------------------------

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override protected function commitProperties() : void {
        super.commitProperties();

        if (_columnWidthsChanged) {
            splitPercentWidths(columnWidths);
            _columnWidthsChanged = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @private
     * Sizes each of the columns in the DataGrid based on the columnWidths property,
     * unless the user has manually resized the columns, then the column widths will
     * not be adjusted.
     */
    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number) : void {
        // Determine how much width is left over for percentage calculations after the fixed
        // widths are allocated.
        var leftoverWidth : Number = unscaledWidth;

        for each (var explicitColWidth : Number in _explicitColWidths) {
            leftoverWidth -= explicitColWidth;
        }

        // Manually adjust the column width before doing super.updateDisplayList. This way when 
        // super.updateDisplayList is called, it can perform any minor adjustments to the columns, 
        // but the column widths will still be pretty consistant with the specified widths.
        if (columns && columnWidths && !_columnsAdjusted && columns.length == columnWidths.length) {
            for (var i : int = 0; i < columnWidths.length; i++) {
                var w : Number = 0;

                if (_explicitColWidths[i]) {
                    w = _explicitColWidths[i];
                }
                else {
                    w = leftoverWidth * (_percentColWidths[i] / 100);
                }

                // Adjust the column's width. After digging through the DataGridColumn, I found 
                // 3 different properties that need to be set to override the default column width 
                // calculations performed by DataGrid and DataGridColumn. They are _width (changed 
                // in the setWidth method), explicitWidth, and preferredWidth.
                columns[i].setWidth(w);
                columns[i].explicitWidth = w;
                columns[i].preferredWidth = w;
            }
        }

        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    //   Private 
    //--------------------------------------

    /**
     * @private
     */
    private function onColumnStretch(event : DataGridEvent) : void {
        _columnsAdjusted = true;
    }

    /**
     * Called from the <code>commitProperties()</code> method to break up the columnWidths
     * into percentage based widths and explicit widths.
     *
     * When we calculate the percentage widths in <code>updateDisplayList()</code> we need
     * to know the remaining available width after explicit widths are subtracted.
     */
    private function splitPercentWidths(values : Array) : void {
        if (columns && columnWidths && columnWidths.length > 0) {
            _percentColWidths = new Object();
            _explicitColWidths = new Object();

            for (var i : uint = 0; i < columnWidths.length; i++) {
                var columnWidth : String = columnWidths[i] + "";

                // If columnWidth contains a '%' then it is a percentage width, otherwise
                // it is an explicit width.
                if (columnWidth.indexOf("%") == -1) {
                    _explicitColWidths[i] = Number(columnWidth);
                }
                else {
                    _percentColWidths[i] = Number(columnWidth.substr(0, columnWidth.length - 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Declare all column widths as at array assigned to 'columnWidths' with the following syntax:

```
 columnWidths = ['70%','30%','100'];
```

Widths without a % sign are treated normally.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "percentWidth" on data grids (that I'm aware of). You can write some code to do it manually ie: set the width to be .1*dataGrid.width for 10%, but that's obviously a bit annoying. I used this solution in the past.

I did a quick google search and found the following link where a guy has extended the DataGrid class to have the functionality that I think you are sinking. You can check out his article here:

[ScalableDataGrid](http://natescodevault.com/2008/10/22/solving-relative-datagrid-column-widths-with-scalabledatagrid/)

I haven't tried using this, so I'd be interested to know if it works.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask you to tell us what "Doesn't work" means; but since percentageWidth is not a property on the [DataGridColumn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html) class, I suspect you mean you're seeing a compiler error?

If you want to size the dataGrid columns using percentages you'll probably have to extend the DataGrid and write the column sizing code yourself.

Comment: No it doesnt give any compile (or run time) error. It simply ignores it. I know I can not find any percentWidth property specified in datagrid column but I meant to ask the way to implement it? In mxml I have always been able to achive it if I provide it in decimals (e.g 0.6,0.2,0.2 for three columns), provided the sum comes to 1 of all columns.  For action script I tried to do the same by having binding variables for width of columns and setting those variables at run time in percent values (using a custom function of course). But it doesnt seem to work either...

Answer (score 0):

like the other posters said, there is no percentWidth property on the mx DataGridColumn, but it is possible to do, you'll need to extend the Flex DataGrid. See here http://www.flexicious.com/Home/DemoFlex4, example 9.

One thing to keep in mind when applying column widths, is to ensure that you set the horizontalScrollPolicy to "on" before you set the column widths.

We actually provide a percentWidth property on our extension of the DataGrid. And the implementation is quite straighforward really:

1) Figure out the total width of the grid
2) Divide it on basis of the percentWidth values
3) Set the horizontalScrollPolicy to on
4) Apply the calculated widths
5) Set the horizontalScrollPolicy back to whatever it was.

This works for us, so it should work for you. Please post here if even after following the above psuedo code or setting the HSCP to "on" it does not apply the widths, and we can try to assist!